# java - Unable to run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run this program for my class. However, this error keeps popping up. I have tried reinstalling eclipse, reinstalling the zip file, and more. However, I keep getting this same answer even with the default code.

Here is the code for the main:

```
package com.snhu.sslserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.math.BigInteger; 
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class ServerController{
    public static String calculateHash(String name) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {  
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");  
        byte[] hash =  md.digest(name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, hash);  
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(number.toString(16));  
        while (hexString.length() < 32){  
            hexString.insert(0, '0');  
        }  
        return hexString.toString();  
     
    } 
    @RequestMapping("/hash")
    public String myHash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

    String data = "Hello Destiny Egan!";
    String hash = calculateHash(data);

    return "<p>data:"+data+" : SHA-256 "+" : "+hash;

    }

}
```

Here is for the tester (which I didn't change anything on):

```
package com.snhu.server;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class ServerApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.snhu</groupId>
    <artifactId>ssl-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ssl-server</name>
    <description>ssl-server skeleton for CS-305</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
              <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
              <version>9.0.1</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I was receiving errors however, I can do the run as. As before I was trying to install. I do not have the option to run as -> Java application.

Here is the error:

```
[INFO] Results:

[INFO]

[ERROR] [1;31mErrors: [m

[ERROR] [1;31m  ServerApplicationTests » IllegalState Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguratio...[m

[INFO]

[ERROR] [1;31mTests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0[m

[INFO]

[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m

[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m

[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m

[INFO] Total time:  5.852 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2023-11-26T18:24:43-08:00

[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test[m [1m(default-test)[m on project [36mssl-server[m: [1;31mThere are test failures.[m

[ERROR] [1;31m[m

[ERROR] [1;31mPlease refer to C:\Users\dessi\eclipse-workspace\CS 305 Module Five Coding Assignment Checksum Verification Code Base (1).zip_expanded\CS 305 Module Five Checksum Verification Assignment Code\module5_skel_student\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.[m

[ERROR] [1;31mPlease refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.[m

[ERROR] -> [1m[Help 1][m

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have tried reinstalling eclipse, reinstalling the zip file, and more. However, I keep getting this same answer even with the default code. I also reached out to my teacher which he had said to just do run it with the java application but that isn't popping up.

Comment: `just do run it with the java application` If this is what your teacher said, you should probably do exactly that.  Spring Boot is for experts only and not for beginners.  Try it with just Java.  If you get stuck, then ask here.

Comment: I am unable to run it, as there is no option to. As when I click run as instead of java application it says (none applicable)

Comment: That's two separate source files for the ServerApplication and ServerController sources, right, not both in one file? How are you importing this zip file you keep mentioning? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Package Name :** Make sure your package name are same in both main class() and test class().

   ```
   //main class package name
   package com.snhu.sslserver;

   //Test class package name
   package com.snhu.server;
   ```
2. **pom.xml modification** : As you using spring boot, you do not need to use explicitly `junit-vintage-engine`. Spring boot manage configurations and version of testing dependencies.

   ```
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
   ```
3. Update Sprig boot version and make use your test classes under main.

Comment: The packages came like that, as the assignment came as pre-coded besides the fix me.

Comment: I am unsure of what to do since I can't select run as -> java application. Since that is what I am supposed to do, but can't.

Comment: Please update java version and spring boot version at pom.xml then build that project.
I will provide a git repo link of your existing code by to night.